# Remapping Mouse Wheel in Mac

Tags: mac, mouse-wheel, button-remapping

I have been trying to remap my mouse wheel up and down actions to keyboard keys in a specific application.  Does anyone know how?

I'm using a steelseries sensei, and the steelseries engine doesn't support it.  It seems I need something more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>TEXTEDIT</appname>
    <equal>com.apple.TextEdit</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <only>TEXTEDIT</only>
    <autogen>__ScrollWheelToKey__ ScrollWheel::UP, KeyCode::A, ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).